# Why local UDP is failing?

Tags: windows, udp, visual-studio-2019

My program cannot receive large UDP datagrams although the code is the same as in Wireshark.

Hello All,
I have a problem with reception of UDP datagrams (Windows 10). My program used TCP and UDP and while TCP works fine, UDP on a semi-regular basis fails with recvfrom(). I compiled Wireshark in a Debug mode and its udpdump.exe receives datagrams 1400 bytes long no problem (locally sent, no internet involved). My program has exactly the same code, but always fails with large datagrams, although usually works with short (~20 bytes) datagrams. At first my UDP client was in a separate thread, now I moved in in the main thread. Still no fun. The only difference with uspdump is that it's pure C while I use C++. Could it be the problem?
Any UDP guru that is able to explain what is happening?
I'd be most grateful for any ideas/hints.
Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to clarify some details. The call to recvfrom() fails with the following: recvfrom failed with error: 10040 (A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself.) Check for the maximum allowed datagram using getsockopt() gives 65507. I'm indeed puzzled.